# is there a way to put two array into one array?

Tags: c#

is there a way to put two arrays into one array so I can use the new array index? in c#

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] arr2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

int[[]] arr3 = {arr1,arr2};
```

Comment: what will you do with arr3? there might be better ways.

Comment: [Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-6.0) is probably the simplest way. But it won't produce a new array, only an enumerable.

Comment: It's probably a mistake to be working with arrays in the first place. There are usually far more appropriate collection types to use.

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the arrays to a single, longer one like `int[] arr3 = arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray()`? Or have an array or arrays as result like `int[][] arr3 = {arr1,arr2};`?

Comment: @KlausGütter or maybe a mutidimensional array `int[,] arr3 = new int[,] { arr1, arr2 };`?

Comment: @SteveB Union will also remove duplicates which might not be desired. [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat) might be the better choice

Comment: @KlausGütter: you are right. I commeted a bit quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `SelectMany()` on arr3 to convert `[[]]` array of array to single flatten array.

```
var flattenArr = arr3.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

---

Or You can use `List<T>.AddRange()` to merge two lists into resultant one.

As you have input array, you need to convert `arr1` and `arr2` to lists first.

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] arr2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

var list1 = arr1.ToList();
var list2 = arr2.ToList();

var result = list1.AddRange(list2).ToArray();  //Here type of result is int[]
```

---

As [@Klaus Gütter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142950/klaus-g%C3%BCtter) suggested in his comment you can use `.Concat()` method to concatenate two different arrays

```
int[] arr3 = arr1.Concat(arr2).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you probably don't want to work with an array, since there are so many better collections. If, however, you insist, the barebones way of doing it is by using Array.Copy:

```cs
// Declare array of the needed length
var arr4 = new int[arr1.Length+arr2.Length];
// Copy the first array into the new array
Array.Copy(arr1, arr4, arr1.Length);
// Copy the second array into the new array, at the end of the first
Array.Copy(arr2, 0, arr4, arr1.Length, arr2.Length);
```